# p5.js How would I prevent a small circle from crossing a diameter of a bigger circle

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Im working of a program that has a circle moving around inside another bigger circle.

```
var offX;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  offX = 0.00;
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  var bigBoy = {
    x: 200,
    y: 200,
    r: 150,
  };
  
  var smallBoy = {
    x: noise(offX) * 400,
    y: map(sin(offX),-1,1,10,380),
    r: 10,
  };
  
  offX += 0.005;
  
  ellipse(bigBoy.x,bigBoy.y,bigBoy.r * 2);
  ellipse(smallBoy.x,smallBoy.y,smallBoy.r * 2);

  var d = dist(bigBoy.x,bigBoy.y,smallBoy.x,smallBoy.y);
  
  text(round(d,0),30,20);
  
  //-------------------------------//
  
  if(d > bigBoy.r - smallBoy.r){
    
    //move away from / dont cross over bigBoy's diameter// 
    
  } else{
    
    //crack on mate//
  }
}
```

could anyone advise me how I would keep the smaller circle within the bigger circles diameter. I would need it to look natural, like the small circle has a force preventing it from leaving the bigger one?

Thanks in advance!
P

Comment: Can you add your question to the end of your post? Welcome to SO

Comment: You will have to check for the position of the small circle in relation to the big one and check that its radius plus its current position is less than the big one, you will have to use sin() and cos(), I think there is an article that discuss this problem, if I find it I'll post it here.

Comment: Check the Nature of code chapter on Vectors here to give you the basic trig and them move on to the next Forces to accomplish what you need. The last example in 2.9 Gravitational Attraction may help, all you need to do is make the attraction smaller and draw the outer circle large enough so the attraction force keeps it in side, hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. limit() was my friend in the end. internal gratitude @RicardoSanchez